# Other series representations for zeta and eta functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

Given that $ \left(\forall s>1\right),\ \zeta\left(s\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n^{s}}} $, and that $ \left(\forall s>0\right),\ \eta\left(s\right)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n^{s}}} $, prove the following formulas :

$$ \left(\forall s>0\right),\ \eta\left(s\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{n}{k}\left(k+1\right)^{-s}}} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(1\right) $$

$$ \left(\forall s>1\right),\ \zeta\left(s\right)=\frac{1}{s-1}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{n}{k}\left(k+1\right)^{1-s}}} \ \ \ \left(2\right) $$

These formulas appear to be algorithms for accelerating the convergence of these series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Euler's transform (ET)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Euler's_transform)

> $$\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^na_n=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nka_{n-k}$$

For the Dirichlet Eta Function we obtain

\begin{align*}
\eta(s)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}&=\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^na_n&&;~a_n=(n+1)^{-s}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nka_{n-k}&&;~\text{ET}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nk(n-k+1)^{-s}&&;~n-k\mapsto k\\
&=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom n{n-k}(k+1)^{-s}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac1{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nk(k+1)^{-s}
\end{align*}

The accelerated series for the Riemann Zeta Function is listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Globally_convergent_series) and a proof may be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317823796_A_New_Proof_of_HHasse's_Global_Expression_for_the_Riemann's_Zeta_Function) (Theorem $10.$ in particular). As far as I can tell the idea is similiar to the one given for $\eta(s)$.

Comment: It converges absolutely only for $\Re(s) > 1$, then you need to show it is analytic, which follows from the way Euler summation behave wrt $a_n\to\sum_{m\le n} a_m$

Comment: Thank you @mrtaurho for your consideration, but can we prove it without using that Euler's transform formula ?

Comment: @CHAMSI That might be possible but I don't know a different approach, to be honest.

Comment: I think I managed to do it without ET :)

Comment: @CHAMSI That's nice! Feel free to post your own answer so that the community can benefit from your approach aswell :)

Comment: Since $ \left(\forall k\in\left[\!\left[0,n\right]\!\right]\right),\ \left(k+1\right)^{-s}=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(s\right)}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}{x^{-s}\,\mathrm{e}^{-\left(k+1\right)x}\,\mathrm{d}x} $, we get that $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{n}{k}\left(k+1\right)^{-s}}=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(s\right)}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}{x^{-s}\,\mathrm{e}^{-x}\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-x}\right)^{n}\mathrm{d}x} $, using the fact that $ \zeta\left(s\right)=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(s\right)}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}{\frac{x^{s-1}}{\mathrm{e}^{x}-1}\,\mathrm{d}x} $, will give us the result.